# How to parse dynamically html code using HTML Agility pack?

Tags: html, dynamic, tags, html-agility-pack, dynamically-generated

I need to parse dynamically generated HMTL code using a HTML Agility pack.

For example this code:

```
<div class="navigation_noClass"> There are 43 articles </div>
```

is not displayed in the Page Source option of the web browser, i.e. this code can only be visible using some inspect tools such as Firebug, Inspect Context ...

Comment: you can format code using four spaces at the start of each line

Answer (score 0):

Right at the moment, it sounds like you're feeding the HTML received directly into the Agility pack and thus missing a few of the (vital?) steps which a regular browser would do.
i.e. the execution of Javascript and / or CSS.

There are numerous option for executing Javascript but most of the reasonably "self contained" options require you recreate the DOM and the associated functionality. Not trivial.

And then there's those occasions where CSS contains content (such as the Before / After pseudo elements). As far as I know, there's not a whole lot of libraries around for simulating CSS behaviour upon a HTML source outside of a browser.

All of this means if you really need to capture the output of Javascript and / or CSS execution, it might be easiest to wire up a browser directly into your app processing pipeline (such as one of the Chromium based offerings) and interrogate its DOM (in a similar manner to the many function web testing suites).

NB: If this is a serious sized server style processing task, you may want to hive off such processing onto dedicated servers / app pools / processes to give your app a fighting chance at a decent up time and / or memory.